# Get only file name in variable in a for loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix, echo

I have a for loop that writes text in a file :

```
for f in $DATA_DIRECTORY 
do 
    echo ' input.'$f '{'
    echo '  copy = ${source.copy}"'$f'.CPY"'
    echo '  data = ${source.data}"'$f'.CSV"'
    echo ' }'
done
```

But the "**f**" variable here looks like this :

```
/path/to/my/file/FILE.TXT
```

What i want to get is only the name of the file, not the full path and its extension:

```
FILE
```

By the way i tried to change my f variable like this so i dont get the extension but it did not work :

```
{$f%%.*}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two lines; chained operators aren't allowed.

```
f=${f##*/}  # Strip the directory
f=${f%%.*}  # Strip the extensions
```

Or, you can use the `basename` command to strip the directory and one extension (assuming you know what it is) in one line.

```
f=$(basename "$f" .txt)
```